# Using global variable in my class causing unexpected syntax

Tags: php, scope

I have a class that requires a variable that is defined out of the scope of it. So i tried using `global` but, this causes this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

I am unsure if I have put it in the wrong place or using the global keyword incorrectly.

My code looks like this:

```
$data = new testClass();

class System
{
    private $values;
    global $data;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function test()
    {           
        return $data->get();
    }
}
$system = new System();
echo $system->test();
```

So i was wondering how do I get the `$data` variable to be defined in my class? My use of global seems to be incorrect, I also put the global declaration in the `__contrust()` function but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the global variable within the function instead of the class:

```
public function test()
{           
    global $data;
    return $data->get();
}
```

EDIT: Alternate idea:

```
class System
    {
        private $values;
        private $thedata;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->thedata = $data;
    }
    public function test()
    {           
        return $this->thedata->get();
    }
}

$data = new testClass();
$system = new System($data);
echo $system->test();
```

Comment: So i have to call global in every function that uses it not just set it at the top of the whole class?

Comment: Yes, but I will update my answer to include an alternate option which may or may not work in your situation (but if you can make it work, it would be better code-standards-wise and so that you won't have to declare the global variable in each function).

Answer (score 2):

> So i was wondering how do I get the $data variable to be defined in my class? My use of global seems to be incorrect, I also put the global declaration in the __contrust() function but that didn't work either.

If you really want to use bad `global` construction, you should do like this:

```
class System
{
    private $values;
    // removed global from here


    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function test()
    {
       // added global here
       global $data;
        return $data->get();
    }
}
```

But OOP principles recommend us to use composition, not global variables. So you can pass the `$data` into your another class via constructor or via setter. Here's some code implementing both approaches:

```
class testClass {
    public function get()
    {
        echo __CLASS__.'::'.__FUNCTION__;
    }
}

class System
{
    private $values;
    private $data;

    public function __construct(testClass $data = null)
    {
        if ($data) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }

    public function setData(testClass $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return $this->data->get();
    }
}

$data = new testClass();
// via constructor
$system = new System($data);
// or via setter
$system = new System;
$system->setData($data);
echo $system->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `$data` when you instantiate the class and then assign it in the constructor, which will make it available to all the methods of the class.

```
class System {

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function index() {
        echo $this->data;
    }

}


$data = 'foo';

$system = new System($data);

echo $system->index();
```

outputs 'foo';

Answer (score -1):

First things first... This could just be a simple "bad PHP syntax" issue.  Look for forgotten ; or in my case... Forgetting that functions actually need the word **function** : )